# How do i execute multiple queries in the same function with the same adapter in ZEND 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, execute

This is the content of  the global.php file:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Mysqli',
        'database' => 'web_builder',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => ''
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
 );
```

This is the content of my model:

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;

class UsersTable extends AbstractTableGateway {

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter) {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }
public function user_login($getData,$session_id){ // manage the user's login 

        $email = $getData['login_email'];
        $password  = $getData['login_password'];
        $select = $this->adapter->query ("select count(*) as counter from users where email = '$email' and  password = '".md5($password)."'");
        $results = $select->execute();
        if ($results->current()['counter'] == 1 ){
            $select->getDataSource()->getResource()->closeCursor();
            $update_user = $this->adapter->query("UPDATE users SET session_id = '".$session_id."' WHERE email = '".$email."'");
            $update_session = $update_user->execute();
            return 1; 
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the update query is not working. If i commented  the count query it works. I observed that i cannot execute multiple queries in the same function for some God know reason :P. I'm getting this message: `Statement couldn't be produced with sql: ......` . Both query works perfectly if i executed them in phpmyadmin. Can anyone explain me why this cannot work ? I'm a little desperate :| ,  I spent severals hours on this

Comment: could this be the reason? email = '$email' -> email = ' ".$email." '

Answer (score 0):

It could be a formatting / preparation issue, taking a look at the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html) it suggests the following format to prepare your statement:

```
$adapter->query('SELECT * FROM `artist` WHERE `id` = ?', array(5));
```

So in your case try formatting it as so:

```
$select = $this->adapter->query ('select count(*) as counter from users where email = ? and  password = ? ', $email , md5($password) );
```

Comment: now i'm getting this message : Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::query() must implement interface Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSetInterface, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\module\Application\src\Application\Model\UsersTable.php on line 63 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter.php on line 166